# Change displayed value after a database entry

Tags: html, angularjs, scope

I'm making a taxi renting service application, which among other things, has a function of renting a taxi. By renting it, a database entry is made into the history array of a certain taxi, including the name/surname of the buyer, the length of the drive and the price according to the rent length. The function that calculates the total sum of gains from renting and passes the result to the html page is being called with an interval, but it does not register the changes that are made in the database until the page is refreshed, but I want the change to be registered automatically, without refreshing. 

Here is the code:

```
var getSumOfAll = function(){
        curProf=0;
        //get sum of all taxies
        sumAll = $scope.getTotalAll($scope.taxies);
        //get the current earnings of the active taxies
        for(var i = 0; i<$scope.taxies.length; i++){
            if(!$scope.taxies[i].available && timeSpent($scope.taxies[i])>=$scope.taxies[i].history[0].length){
                $scope.updateRent($scope.taxies[i], $scope.taxies[i]._id, $scope.taxies[i].history[0].length);
            }
            if(!$scope.taxies[i].available){
                curProf += $scope.getCurrentProfit($scope.taxies[i]);
            }
        }

        console.log($scope.taxies[0].history[0])

        //show current gains
        $scope.gains = curProf+sumAll;
    }
```

getTotalAll code:

```
$scope.getTotalAll = function(taxies){
        var total = 0;
        //console.log(taxies.length)
        for(var i = 0; i < taxies.length; i++){
            for(var j = 0; j < taxies[i].history.length; j++){
                if(taxies[i].history[j].price) total += taxies[i].history[j].price;
            }
        }
        return total;
    }
```

Use in the html site:

```
<div ng-controller="HeaderController" class="md-padding" style="text-align: center;">
<div ng-init="getTaxies();">
    <a href="#!"><img src="/img/logo/taxi.png" id="logo"></a>
    <md-toolbar>
        <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
            <md-truncate id="sum">Sum of gains: {{gains}}</md-truncate>
            <span flex></span>
            <md-button class="md-raised" ng-disabled="0>=gains" ng-click="buyTaxi()">Buy a taxi</md-button>
            <md-button class="md-raised" ng-click="addTaxi()">Add a taxi</md-button>
        </div>
    </md-toolbar>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to call the getSumofAll function after a specific interval of time? right?

Comment: I am calling it every two seconds:
$interval(getSumOfAll, 2000);

Comment: What I want is for this function to register the changes after I make a new entry in the taxies database (e.g. a new rent with a certain price) and display the change on the html site.

Comment: You should read about the basic handling "Web API's". This will help ya.

Comment: are you getting new values in sumAll every 2 sec?

Comment: I think you need to consider `promises`  i.e. `$q` . can you write more detailed code as in the flow in which it is being called. I cant see `$interval` in your shared code. We can only make wild guesses

Comment: @AkashAgrawal This could be the problem. I thought I was getting them, but apparently I am not. How do I then retrieve updated taxies? (Sorry, I'm kind of a newbie in Angularjs..)

Comment: @ShashankVivek Here is the gihub repository of this app: https://github.com/vidvidvid/taxiapp
You can find this controller under client/controllers/header

Comment: can you paste the getTotalAll function's code?

Comment: I will paste it in the original post.

Comment: @AkashAgrawal I fixed the problem by retrieving new data every time by calling the new function, thank you for helping! :)

Answer (score 0):

Retrieving updated data was not possible due to an unchanged value in the sumAll function. I fixed this by retrieving updated data every time by calling the factory function. (return $http.get('/api/taxies'));

```js
var getSumOfAll = () => {
        dataFactory.getTaxies().then(function(response){ //make a get req from this address
            taxies = response.data; 
            curProf=0;

            //show current gains
            $scope.gains = getTotalAll(taxies);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Great, thats what I was talking about.